# Performance Issues with Derived Table in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, derived-table

I am having trouble using a derived table in MySQL. Does using a derived table inherently slow down the processing of a query?

Here is the query I am trying to run. It won't execute and just times out.

It does succeed. Really, I have isolated the problem to the last join. When I take out the last join it works fine. But when I add the last join back in it refuses to execute.

```
SELECT cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS ANSWER_ID, 
       cr.CONSUMER_ID as VIEWER_ID, 
       cr.ACTION_LOG_ID, 
       nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS QUESTION_ID, 
       nc.SENDER_CONSUMER_ID AS REPLIER_ID, 
       ces.EXPERT_SCORE AS REPLIER_EXPERTISE, 
       cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID AS DOMAIN
    FROM (SELECT 234 AS CONSUMER_ID, 
    ACTION_LOG_ID, 
    COMMUNICATIONS_ID 
    FROM consumer_action_log 
    WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4) AS cr
JOIN network_communications AS nc ON 
cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=nc.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
JOIN communication_interest_mapping AS cim ON 
nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cim.COMMUNICATION_ID
JOIN consumer_expert_score AS ces ON 
nc.SENDER_CONSUMER_ID=ces.CONSUMER_ID
        AND cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID=ces.CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID;
```

Comment: What happens when you run that subquery by itself?  Does it succeed? I would do an explain on the subquery by itself, and then another one on the query as a whole.

Comment: It does succeed. Really, I have isolated the problem to the last join. When I take out the last join it works fine. But when I add the last join back in it refuses to execute.

Comment: What are the results of an EXPLAIN on that query?  Do you have an index on both consumer_id/expert_id in each table?  I would recommend an index covering both columns in each table.

Comment: Also, for optimization help, you should post the results of the SHOW CREATE TABLE queries for each table involved (besides the results of EXPLAIN).

Comment: I am new to SQL and programming. How do you utilize a index. Or are they taken advantage of automatically.

Comment: The indexes worked! THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps... Here's some mysql CREATE INDEX statements.  Basically, if you can add indexes, make sure there's an index that covers each of your columns that connect 2 or more tables.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nc
ON network_communications(COMMUNICATIONS_ID);

CREATE INDEX idx_cim
ON communication_interest_mapping(COMMUNICATION_ID);

CREATE INDEX idx_ces
ON consumer_expert_score(CONSUMER_ID, CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID);
```

Derived tables aren't inherently bad, but in this case (see below) you're pulling all the records from consumer_action_log that have a comm_type_id of 4.  There doesn't seem to be a connection back to the other tables.  That might be the cause of the sql never returning.

```
SELECT cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID, 
           cr.CONSUMER_ID, 
           cr.ACTION_LOG_ID, 
           nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID, 
           nc.SENDER_CONSUMER_ID, 
           ces.EXPERT_SCORE, 
           cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID

    FROM (SELECT 234 AS CONSUMER_ID, 
             ACTION_LOG_ID, 
             COMMUNICATIONS_ID 
             FROM consumer_action_log 
             WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4) AS cr

JOIN network_communications AS nc ON 
         cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=nc.COMMUNICATIONS_ID

JOIN communication_interest_mapping AS cim ON 
         nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cim.COMMUNICATION_ID

JOIN consumer_expert_score AS ces ON 
         nc.SENDER_CONSUMER_ID=ces.CONSUMER_ID
        AND cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID=ces.CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the indexes that should exist on your lookup tables as pointed out in anser by John, I would ensure you have an index on COMM_TYPE_ID in your consumer_action_log table too.

Then, add one keyword to your clause... I've always seen great results when a query is well organized instead of relying on the query engine to optimze...[see another sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808050/slow-sql-query-using-the-same-table-in-two-different-joins-causes-query-to-becom/4808547#4808547)

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
         cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS ANSWER_ID,
         cr.CONSUMER_ID as VIEWER_ID,  
         etc... rest of your query...
```

It might be the optimizer is trying to look at other tables to figure out what to get.  See comments in other StackOverflow answer I've provided link to.